# python selenium scrape render javascript

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have been reading all of these SO posts and read through the Selenium documentation, I have tried the "expected_conditions" but nothing is working...

Here's what I am trying to do - I am building a scraper, and decided to test it against an amazon product detail page - on that page there is a div tag with the ID: books-entity-teaser which is rendered by JS code when that tag is visible on the page...

However, when I execute my code that tag is completely empty

Can someone point to what I am missing

I tried waiting for the tag to load and then getting the page source

`WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element((By.ID, 'books-entity-teaser')))`

Here's my python code

```
def scrape(self, url: str = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/1408865270'):
        self.browser.get(url)

        page_state = self.browser.execute_script('return document.readyState;')

        scroll_pause_time = 0.5

        # Get scroll height
        last_height = self.browser.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')

        while True:
            # Scroll down to bottom
            self.browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;')

            # Wait to load page
            time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = self.browser.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height

        page_source = self.browser.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'books-entity-teaser')))

        return page_source
```

Expected Results:
[image: populated div tag]

Actual Results:
[image: empty div tag]

Comment: use the correct expected_condition.  the example you showed is waiting for a visible element to become invisible.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg - I appreciate your comment but I have tried multiple expected_condition statements: presence_of_element_located, text_to_be_present_in_element - however to satisfy your comment, I will update the code